# Why case statement returning records whose condition does not met?

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to fetch only single record from database for whose id is met in case statement

Student table data:

[image]

SQL query:

[image]

Output:

[image]

What is wrong with the query?

I tried to get a single record specific to the matching id but it is returning all the records

Comment: The only way to discard record is by using a `WHERE` clause, the current query will bring everything in the table, and then select `id` and then calculate a column for each row. Maybe you meant to do `SELECT id FROM student WHERE id = 5` ?

Comment: @Jhilton  i know about the where clause but what here i tried is whats the purpose of case statement in docs it specifies that only returns matching records

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). There is absolutely nothing in your post that couldn't be done in text. Also, your use of CASE is incorrect. It doesn't do what you seem to think it does. You should find a decent SQL tutorial to learn the language basics - it will save you lots of struggles in the future. SO is not a tutorial site.

Comment: `CASE` only returns a specific value for a column based on some condition - it **DOES NOT** limit the rows being returned - that's what you need a `WHERE` clause for.....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch only id = 5 records then you have to use the WHERE clause which will filter the records.
CASE statement is just a conditional statement it won't filter output.
If you want to use your same query then try below

```
SELECT id, name,
CASE id =5 THEN "Found" END FROM student WHERE id =5;
```

As we already added WHERE clause which will filter id = 5 record, we no need CASE statement you can directly hard code "Found" in the last column.
If our output have multiple types in the id column and if you need to populate more that one status in the last column then you can go for CASE statement, unless it's waste of time in the query execution

Try below

```
SELECT id, name,"Found" FROM student WHERE id =5;
```